# Difference between Delegate.BeginInvoke and Thread.Start

Tags: .net, multithreading

Existing related questions here talk about differences between:

- Delegate.BeginInvoke and Control.BeginInvoke
- Control.BeginInvoke and Thread.Start

But what are the differences between Delegate.BeginInvoke and Thread.Start?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Thread.Start` starts a new OS thread to execute the delegate. When the delegate returns, the thread is destroyed. This is quite a heavy-weight operation (starting and destroying a thread) so you typically only do it if the method is going to be long-running.

`Delegate.BeginInvoke` will call the delegate on a thread pool thread. Once the method returns, the thread is returned to the pool to be reused by another task. The advantage of this is that queueing a method to the thread pool is relatively light-weight because you don't have to spin up a whole new thread every time.

`Control.BeginInvoke` invokes the method on the thread for the control. UI components are inherently single-threaded and every interaction with a UI control must be done on the thread that created it. `Control.BeginInvoke` is a handy way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

- Delegate.BeginInvoke uses the [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) to execute the method ([See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc.aspx)).
- [Thread.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a9fyxz7d.aspx) creates a full new thread.

See this question: [differences in the different ways to make concurrent programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743883/differences-in-the-different-ways-to-make-concurrent-programs) for more info on the differences between the various ways of running concurrent code in .net.